# How String is immutable in java

Tags: java, string

I have the following code, which I have written to check how string is immutable.

**My code is:**

```
class Check
{
   public static void main(String k[])
   {
      String a1="JohnPlayer";
      a1.concat("America");//line no 6
      String a2="America";//line no 7
      a1=a1+a2;//line no 8
      System.out.println("Value of a1="+a1);
   }
}
```

In line no 6, when I use `concat`, it print only "JohnPlayer",
     while If I concatenate a1 and a2 using `a1+a2`, it prints the concatenated value "JohnPlayerAmerica" . In this case, how can I say `String` is immutable?

Comment: Use `System.identityHashCode()` on each object and see the values. Each object is unique. `concat` returns a "new" String

Comment: String _objects_ are immutable.  String _references_ are not.

Answer (score 1):

`String` is immutable.

```
a1.concat("America");
```

returns a new `String` instance which you ignore. `a1` is unchanged.

```
a1=a1+a2;
```

creates a new `String` instance and assigns it to the `a1` variable. The original `String` referenced by `a1` is unchanged.

This is similar to writing :

```
a1 = a1.concat("America");
```

Comment: String doesn't provide any setter method..every time a new String only gets created

Comment: am not getting , these two line that is a1=a1+a2; i know that it assign these value but still it concat and print the value like JohnPlayerAmerica,while in first case it is not?

Comment: @user7344668 writing `a1.concat("America")` without doing anything with the returned new String has a similar meaning to writing `a1+a2` without doing anything with the returned new String. The only difference is that the latter doesn't pass compilation, since the result of the concatenation operator must be used somehow (assigned to a variable, returned to the calling method, etc...), while the result of a method call can be ignored.